# Table in listview

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to list data in a `ListView`, and each row has 4 columns and 1 that spans over 4.

How can I achieve the following for each entry in listning:

[image]

Xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="myMood.Views.Entries"
             Icon="ic_view_headline_white_24dp.png"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:myMood.ViewModels">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModels:EntriesViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MoodEntries}" 
              HasUnevenRows="True"
              Margin="20">
        <ListView.Header>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Start">                
                <Image Source="ic_date_range_black_24dp.png"></Image>
                <Image Source="ic_local_hotel_black_24dp.png"></Image>
                <Image Source="ic_directions_run_black_24dp.png"></Image>
                <Image Source="ic_done_all_black_24dp.png"></Image>
            </StackLayout>
        </ListView.Header>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Label Text="{Binding EntryDate}"></Label>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Sleep}"></Label>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Stress}"></Label>
                    <Label Text="{Binding AchivedGoals}"></Label>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Comment}"></Label>
                </ViewCell>                
            </DataTemplate>            
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>    
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: use a Grid in your ViewCell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Jason suggested, you can use a grid like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MoodEntries}" 
          HasUnevenRows="True"
          Margin="20">
    <ListView.Header>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Start">
            <Image Source="ic_date_range_black_24dp.png"></Image>
            <Image Source="ic_local_hotel_black_24dp.png"></Image>
            <Image Source="ic_directions_run_black_24dp.png"></Image>
            <Image Source="ic_done_all_black_24dp.png"></Image>
        </StackLayout>
    </ListView.Header>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid ColumnSpacing="2"
                      RowSpacing="2">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                           Text="{Binding EntryDate}"
                           BackgroundColor="Yellow"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" 
                           Text="{Binding Sleep}"
                           BackgroundColor="Green"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                           Text="{Binding Stress}"
                           BackgroundColor="Blue"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                           Text="{Binding AchivedGoals}"
                           BackgroundColor="Silver"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                           Text="{Binding Comment}"
                           BackgroundColor="Pink"/>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Notice that Cell elements can have only one child. In this case it is the `Grid` I've added**

You can get more information about the layouts that Xamarin.Forms provide at [xamarin developers site](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/)